How to mount NTFS3 drives/partitions which I have full access to?
I have 2 OS on my computer. 1 archlinux and 1 windows.
I use NTFS3 and kernel 6.10
Operating System: Arch Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.5.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.10.7-arch1-1 (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: 20WKA000CD
System Version: ThinkPad X13 Gen 2i

I want to mount my windows C: and D: partition on my Linux OS, and I want to see them every time I open my computer.
I edited my fstab as this:
/dev/nvme0n1p3          /home/firestar/C        ntfs3   uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000             0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p5          /home/firestar/D        ntfs3   uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000             0 0

but there are still some directories like C:/User/Firestar/xxxx is still non-writable:
(base) [firestar@Archlinux Firestar]$ ls -l
total 12648
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 03:53  AppData
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       33 May  1 03:53 'Application Data' -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 11:53  Contacts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       61 May  1 03:53  Cookies -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCookies
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   212992 Sep  2 22:21  Desktop
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar     8192 Sep  2 22:05  Documents
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar    20480 Sep  2 22:19  Downloads
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 11:53  Favorites
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   354240 Jul  6 16:33  hsi_spectrum_20141020_155000.fits
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar    48960 Jul  6 16:33  hsi_srm_20141020_155000.fits
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 Jul  5 22:47  IDLWorkspace
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar     4096 Sep  4 10:43  IntelGraphicsProfiles
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 Jul  6 12:13  JHelioviewer-SWHV
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 11:53  Links
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       31 May  1 03:53 'Local Settings' -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Local
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 11:53  Music
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       27 May  1 03:53 'My Documents' -> ./../../Users/Firestar/Documents
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       69 May  1 03:53  NetHood -> './../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar 10223616 Sep  4 10:43  NTUSER.DAT
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar    65536 May  1 14:36  NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TM.blf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   524288 May  1 03:53  NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   524288 May  1 03:53  NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 03:53  ntuser.dat.LOG1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   950272 May  1 03:53  ntuser.dat.LOG2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar       20 May  1 03:53  ntuser.ini
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar     4096 Sep  4 10:43  OneDrive
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 Jul  5 22:47  Perforce
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar     4096 Sep  2 22:21  Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       69 May  1 03:53  PrintHood -> './../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Printer Shortcuts'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       58 May  1 03:53  Recent -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Recent
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 May  1 11:53 'Saved Games'
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar     4096 May  1 12:09  Searches
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       58 May  1 03:53  SendTo -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/SendTo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       61 May  1 03:53  Templates -> ./../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Templates
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar        0 Jun 13 22:11  Videos
lrwxrwxrwx 1 firestar firestar       62 May  1 03:53  「开始」菜单 -> './../../Users/Firestar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu'
(base) [firestar@Archlinux Firestar]$

Also, I have a NTFS USB drive, and it is not in the fstab, it has also 2 directories which are non-writable and I don't know why:
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 May  1 11:55 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Apr 21 23:57  Astronomy
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar  49152 Jun 23 14:48  Books
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 May  1 10:38  Documents
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Jul 12  2023  Games
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Dec  8  2022  Hannah
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   8192 Jan 19  2021  HF
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Feb  3  2024  Installers
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   8192 Aug 26  2023  PKU
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Jan 31  2024 'PKU Courses'
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Jun 18  2020  SS
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Feb 20  2024 'System Volume Information'
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar      0 Jan 16  2022  Treasures
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 Jul 14  2022  Wallpapers
dr-xr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar  20480 Feb  3  2024  小提琴谱
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar   4096 May  1 00:54  照片
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar  16384 Dec 21  2023  电影和视频
drwxr-xr-x 1 firestar firestar 655360 Oct 22  2022  音乐

How to mount NTFS3 drives/partitions which I have full access to? Like, how to write my fstab or default mount options? I have no fast-boot nor bitlocker.

Depending on kernel you may want ntfs-3g. Jan 2024 use ntfs-3g not ntfs3 if older kernel
https://www.heiko-sieger.info/does-the-linux-ntfs3-driver-corrupt-directories/
mount | grep -i -e ntfs -e fuseblk
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2499994

But I use a very new kernel and I don't want ntfs-3g due to its poor performance.

You're solving this backwards. Get either ntfs3 or ntfs-3g working, then improve performance. Were the drives ever mounted on a Windows system with "Fast boot" set? AFAIK, some Windows updates helpfully re-enable  "Fast boot". Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
